# How can I read all data from a serialPort before continuing? c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

So I have this application that reads data from a serialPort.  The serialPort responds with different responses depending on the command sent to it.  When I send one particular command, I need to read back possibly a few hundred lines of text.  As of now I can only read as many lines as possible that can be read during my thread.sleep.

I'm using thread.sleep(500) to ensure command response has fully been output & read. But my data that is being read from the serialPort grows larger with each execution, so a sleep will not work.

I've searched around trying to find the correct way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

```
public void sendCommandToPort(string command)
    {
        try
        {                
            serialPort1.Write(command);
            serialPort1.Write("\r\n");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); 
    }


private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {           
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        readInData += sp.ReadExisting();
    }
```

Comment: Are you really familiar with C# events registering, and where are you calling `DataReceivedHandler` and what is `readInData`?

Comment: @LeiYang `DataReceivedHandler` is set to the RecievedHandler when initializing the serialport settings. `serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);` . `readInData` is a string that I am appending read in values to. So after all of my data has be received it is then accessed using `readInData`, then I parse this string for data segments I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to know if you got all of the data:

1. Have the sender tell you how many bytes (or lines) it's going to send, and then you read until you've received that many bytes (or lines).
2. Have the sender and receiver agree that some particular text is the end of the message. For example, the sender will send a blank line, or a line that contains only "END", or a Control-Z character. *Something* that will signify the end of the message.

Otherwise, you can't possibly know when the sender is done.